# Codename One iOS Statusbar on landscape orientation

Tags: codenameone

I think that the iOS Statusbar doesn’t make sense when the device is landscape orientated. How can I make a Codename One app showing the Statusbar only on portrait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll add support for it in the code freeze which should land on the 20th.

`landscapeTitleUiidBool` should have impacted the status bar too so it would have the `StatusBarLandscape` UIID when running in landscape. See the discussion about the `landscapeTitleUiidBool` theme constant here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-back-command-behavior.html

To do this you would just need to override the `StatusBarLandscape` UIID and define `landscapeTitleUiidBool` to `true`.

Comment: Ok, at the moment it doesn't work in the Simulator with iOS skin. Do you mean that it will work in four days?

Comment: Yes. The hint is already implemented for `Title`, `TitleCommand` etc. but `StatusBar` ignores it. I fixed it so `StatusBarLandscape` will be used if that theme constant is defined. But it will only go into the code freeze on the 20th.